# Make simple_form honor my blank/empty label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using simple_form v2.1.0 in a Rails 3.2.13 app. I have a simple_form where I want to have a checkbox show up with an inline label, and I want to have an "empty" normal label. This way, the label's container should remain in place and the checkbox will be properly positioned with the other form elements.

If I set `:label => ""` or `:label => " "` or `:label => nil` or don't provide a `:label` at all, I end up with the field name as the label.

If I set `:label => false`, the label and containing elements aren't rendered at all (so the checkbox appears at the far left of the page).

If I set `:label => "&nbsp;"`, I end up with the literal text `&nbsp;`, as expected.

It seems there is no way to tell simple form to leave the label there, just don't put any text in its container.

Here is an example form where I'm trying to setup an empty label for a checkbox with an inline label.

```
<%= simple_form_for @model ... %>
    <%= f.input :sticky, :label => "", :inline_label => "Sticky?", :as => :boolean ... %>
<% end %>
```

But simple_form thinks it's smarter than me and defaults the label. I wish it only did that if I hadn't specifically supplied a label!

[image: Simple form doesn't allow blank labels!]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `:label` value to `false`.

**UPDATE:** Since SimpleForm is supposed to rely on ActionView to render the elements, you can use this hackish solution: set the label in your locale file to empty string, like this

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      model_name_underscored:
        sticky: ' '
```

Comment: Thought I covered that but apparently not! Updated my question with that example. That causes the label and containing elements to not be rendered at all, so the checkbox shows at the far left of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `:label` attribute in your input completely and instead using `form.label` for the empty label.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label

Instead of using an empty label you could position your check box with CSS.

Comment: This pulls the label outside of the "row" so it would now appear above the checkbox which is now at the far-left of page. I realize I can fix this by manually adding the label elements, etc. But I think this should work as-is (if I provide a "" label, just do as I say). I was going to report the issue but wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong. For now I just won't use inline labels.

Answer (score 0):

Was having similar troubles. In your form defaults just do this:

`defaults: { :label => 'blanklabel', label_html: { class: 'blanklabel'}`

Then in your CSS, just set the label text color to white:

`.blanklabel { color: white; }`